# Change branch after using the --branch arg

Tags: git

I want to change the branch after my repo was cloned with this command:

```
git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://example.com/Repo.git Repo
```

How can I checkout now e.g. the develop branch?

When I execute:

```
git checkout develop
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec 'origin/develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any idea?

Some commands I tried (which didn't work):

```
git remote set-branches --add origin develop
git fetch origin
git pull origin develop:develop
```

Comment: `git remote set-branches --add` *should* work; what happened when you ran it? Also, try `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` and see what the resulting output is.

Comment: @torek When I run those commands the error message doesn't change.

Comment: That wasn't the question: what output, if any, did `git remote set-branches --add` produce, *and*, what output—there *should* be some—does `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` produce? (preferably, for `git config --get-all`, both before running `git remote set-branches --add`, and after, although presumably "before" is too late)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cloned the project you have **limited** which branch to clone along with the number of commits to download.

Therefor you can't switch branches to a different branch without updating your local repository since it will need to contain all the relevant data of the given branch.

In your case you will have to clone the full repo or to fetch the desired branch.

#### Switch to un cloned branch

```
# create a new branch with the desired name
git checkout -b develop

# pull the remote changes locally to your machine
git pull origin develop
```

---

`git clone --branch` is very similar to passing `--[no-]single-branch` option to the clone.

#### `git clone --branch`

> `--[no-]single-branch`
>
> **Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch**, either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at.
>
> Further fetches into the resulting repository **will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning**.
>
> If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch when `--single-branch` clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

---

Here you can see the different results in the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: When I try the first option I get a strange bug: Both branches have the same head which is wrong. Right now I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Both of them might have the same one is you started from a scratch

Comment: I ended in cloning the repo in a second directory.

Comment: Interesting idea. However while using my workaround I found out that I have to use the ssh connection instead of https, well I know that I can change that ether, but it seems to be more efficiently to use a distinct folder.